# Bootstrap - how to make the image being scaled down to fit the window height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make the image overflow height responsive?

The images I have sometimes have long heights which make the window scroll bar visible.

[image]

So I want to make these heights responsive - to make the image being scaled down to fit the window height.

[image]

Is it possible?

CSS,

```
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}

.row-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;

    border: 4px solid red;
}

.centering {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid text-center">
        <div>
            <img src="images/xxx.jpg" class="img-responsive centering">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is large and its height is longer than the window's height.

Comment: no it won't as you can see it on my first image.

Comment: use `100vh` as images `height`.

Comment: with css3 can use `vh` units ... stands for *"viewport height"*. `max-height:90vh;`

Comment: Have you tried .img-responsive class ?

Comment: @OliverQueen yes i did. please see my code.

Comment: Ahh. My apologies. I'm on mobile and formatting is iffy to look at.

Comment: If possible (?) you could make your life easier by putting your image as centered background for container , then a background-size: contain  will do the job for you...

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. I just have to remove `class="img-responsive"` from my img tag. it should not be used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `height: 100%` and `vertical-align: top` on `img` and on **parent** element use `height: 100vh`

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x850">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. it does not work on my chrome for some reasons! :(

Comment: @teelou what do you mean by `it does not work` `:)`?

Comment: sorry, i mean it still looks the same as the original problem I have when I use a real image instead of `<img src="http://placehold.it/400x850">`.

Comment: if you try to replace that placeholder image with an actual large image, you know what i mean...

Comment: This must work and there is no difference in images it probably conflicts with some of your other css code. Use some other class instead of `div` and `img`

Comment: oh actually the **bug** is caused by the bootstraps img-responsive! `<img src="images/xxx.jpg" class="img-responsive">`

Comment: Yes `img-responsive` might be problem here is example with bootstrap included https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/459/

Comment: thank you very much for the help and using a 'real' image.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap overwrite this style for `img` and make img `height: auto` if you use `img-responsive` class so you must remove it or you could use `height: 100% !important;` which is not good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `.centering` class by the built-in `.center-block` of bootstrap

Then add a new class .myimg

```
.myimg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wo2eysh8/3/

Comment: This image goes off the bottom and start a scroll if you make the screen shorter. He wants the image to resize down to fit.

Comment: Try with `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`